# OpenVPN doesn't use remote gateway by default

Tags: openvpn

I've setup an OpenVPN server, clients can connect without any problem, but they still use their existing internet connections, and still have their existing public IP's.

How is it possible to basically set "Use default gateway on remote network" to TRUE, on the OpenVPN client side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate server side settings to push the default gateway to the clients.  This isn't really a client side setting.  Although I suppose you can manually modify the routing table on the client but that's not something that the average user will put up with.

This is documented on OpenVPN's website here. http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect

Comment: I tried to add that remote-gateway clause to the advanced config section in the routers configuration, but it didn't work. I might need to SSH into the router and check the config file actually contains that clause.